# Hourly price notifications on Linux

Tags: linux, exchange-rate, tools

I'm running Debian & Ubuntu and I've been using [this script](https://gist.github.com/ErikBjare/8332003) running in a terminal for a while but I find I easily get obsessed with the price. Instead I'd rather get, say hourly, desktop notifications.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about some particular script, not crytocurrencies in general

Comment: Agreed, this is technically programming so it might be better suited for http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I was initially looking for a premade solution, the answer became programming-oriented when I couldn't find any. The question was never about the script, it was just some background to my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I modified the script and used notify-send to get what I wanted. I run the lightweight notification daemon `xfce4-notifyd` but most desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, Xfce) should have one preinstalled (for example Gnome's `notification-daemon`).

It depends on the `jq` command, so make sure you install it first using your package manager.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Requires jq

# Remember to chmod +x!
#
# Add the following cron-job (using "crontab -e") to run at hourly intervals:
#     0 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /bin/bash <SCRIPT_PATH_GOES_HERE> > /dev/null 2>&1
# Change <SCRIPT_PATH_GOES_HERE> to the appropriate name

BTCE_PRICE="$(curl -s https://btc-e.com/api/2/btc_usd/ticker | jq '.ticker.last')"
MTGOX_PRICE="$(curl -s http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast | jq '.data.last.display' | cut -d "\"" -f 2)"

notify-send "MtGox:     $MTGOX_PRICE
BTC-e:      \$$BTCE_PRICE"
```

Also available [here](https://gist.github.com/ErikBjare/8332113)

In order to run it on hourly intervals add the following line to your crontab using `crontab -e`:

```
0 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /bin/bash <SCRIPT_PATH_GOES_HERE> > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is called `btce_ticker.sh`, the following line would do it:

```
while true; do btce_ticker.sh; sleep 3600; done
```

The `sleep 3600` sleeps for an hour before looping around and running the script again.

Comment: I don't want a terminal notification, instead I'd like a desktop notification. I solved it but can't answer my own question yet (apparently a forced 8h delay) since I have <10 rep. The script is here however: https://gist.github.com/ErikBjare/8332113

Comment: @erb: I note that you didn't actually say "desktop" in your original question.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to mention that, sorry.